# hypothesis test for discrete disributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, discrete-data

I am interested in the number of instances of feature $F$ among the members of two populations, $A_1$ and $A_2$.

e.g. $F$ is a some special genetic element that may occur several times within a single gene.   $A_1$ is a set of $n_1$ genes, and $A_2$ is a set of $n_2$ genes.  So for each element $a_{1,i}$ of $A_1$, I observe the number $x_{1,i}$ instances of $F$ in $a_{1,i}$.  Similarly for $A_2$.

How can I test that the **DISCRETE** distribution of occurrences of $F$ is the same for population $A_1$ vs. $A_2$?

I created the empirical distributions $D_1, D_2$ of $F$ in $A_1, A_2$, respectively.   Again: $D_1,D_2$ are **discrete** - their support is $\mathbb{N}$.

Since the distribution is discrete, it seems that many standard non-paramtetric tests (i.e. Kolmogorov-Smirnov) do not apply.  Since the data is *count* and not categorical, then $\chi^2$ goodness of fit does not apply.

Comment: Even if the data were not discrete, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov would not be suitable as your data are paired

Comment: Actually, @Glen_b, Kolmogorov-smirnov would be correct.  The test is if the *distributions* of $F$ are the same, which is exactly what Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests.  The relationship between populations $A_1$ and $A_2$ is irrelevant.  ($A_1 \subset A_2$ in my case)

Comment: The derivation of the distribution of the statistic under the null relies on the variates being independent. If they're pairwise dependent the ecdfs won't differ as much as they should under the null. The derivation of the distribution of the statistic under the null - indeed, even the property of it being distribution-free - also relies on the distributions being continuous. Both these effects will lead you to have a more conservative test.

Comment: See [here](http://i.imgur.com/k71rGen.png) for an example of the problem -- the black shows what the distribution of p-values under the null looks like when you have continuous distributions and large sample size. The red shows what happens when the values are pairwise correlated.